# Postgres GRANT ROLE of db owner to other another user not doing what expected. What am I missing?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, sql-grant

I am a bit baffled here. Using pg 9.6

```
CREATE USER user1;
CREATE DATABASE mydb with OWNER user1;
CREATE TABLE x ...;
CREATE USER user2; 
GRANT user1 to user2;
```

Login as `user2`.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE x ...;
CREATE TABLE z ...;
```

All is good up to here.

Login as `user1` (DB owner).

```
SELECT FROM z; -- fails; table is owned by user2
```

Shouldn't the db owner have access to ALL objects?

Also, if I:

```
CREATE USER user3;
GRANT user1 /* db owner */ TO user3;
```

I cannot access objects created by `user2` even though `user3` has role granted from DB owner.

Answer (score 2):

Permissions on a database have nothing to do with permissions on other objects in the database, so you can be denied access to database objects even if you are database owner.

Ownership of a database means that you have all privileges on the database object itself and can grant them to others: `CONNECT` to the database, `CREATE` schemas and `TEMPORARY` tables. Furthermore, you can `ALTER` and `DROP` the database.

If you grant the database owner to another user, that user gets all the permissions of the database owner, but not the right to `ALTER` or `DROP` the database (unless `SET ROLE` is used to “become” the database owner).

Answer (score 2):

GRANT comes in two forms: grant on database objects and grant on roles, and they are quite different:

[9.1 docs for GRANT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-grant.html)

The last line in the syntax section is the GRANT you are attempting. Notice the grant is on a role, not a user, but in PostgreSQL a role is a user:

> "A role can be thought of as either a database user, or a group of
>   database users, depending on how the role is set up".

[roles - 9.1 docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/user-manag.html)

This serverfault link might help:
[postgresql-what-does-grant-all-privileges-on-database-do](https://serverfault.com/questions/198002/postgresql-what-does-grant-all-privileges-on-database-do)

Comment: "in PostgreSQL a role is a user" it is the other way round, right? a user is a special role with LOGIN privileges